# Laravel 5.* - Eloquent Many to Many Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have the following tables

```
USERS = username | email | name 
FOLLOWERS = user_id | follower_id
```

When a logged-in user clicks on "follow" my code saves his id inside `followers.follower_id`, and the id of user who he wants to follow is saved inside `followers.user_id`.

To see how many followers a user has and how many users a user is following I use:

```
$followers = Follower::where('user_id', $user->id)->count();
$following = Follower::where('follower_id', $user->id)->count();
```

This works well, but I would like to show information about the followers of one user. I've tried the following:

```
$first_follower = $followers[0]->user->username;
```

But it return the user followed not the follower.

I am wondering how I can get information about the follower

**User Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['username','email','name'];

public function follow() {
  return $this->hasMany('Shop\Follower');    
}
```

**Follower Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id','follower_id'];

public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('Shop\User');
}
```

Comment: you should use many to many relationhips to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right the followers are instances of the User class/model, so you don't need a Follower model. You can just define a  [Many To Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

In your User model you can add:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Shop\User', 'followers', 'user_id ', 'follower_id');
}

public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Shop\User', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Than you can access the user followers just by `$user->followers` which will return a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) and with `$user->following` you can access the ones that the user is following.

```
//Get the count of all followers for $user
$count = $user->followers()->count();

//Get the count of all followed by $user
$count = $user->following()->count();

//Get the username of the first follower
$follower = $user->followers()->first();
echo $follower->username;

//Loop trough all followers
foreach ($user->followers as $follower) {
     echo $follower->username;
}
```

Defining this relation can help you save/delete followers just by using the `attach()` and `detach()` methods

```
// The $user will be followed by an user with $followerId
// A record in the `followers` table will be created with
// user_id = $user->id and follower_id = $followerId
$user->followers()->attach($followerId);

// The $user will stop be followed by an user with $followerId
$user->followers()->detach($followerId);
```

**A side note:** 
There is a difference between calling the `followers()` method and calling the `followers` property. The first will return `BelongsToMany` relation and you can call all the Eloquent query builder method on it and the later will return a `Collection`

```
/** @var Illuminate\Support\Collection */
$user->followers;

/** @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany */
$user->followers();
```

Answer (score 0):

An example how you should implement relations, is above. It's many users to many users thru followers table. You probably dont need a follower model, cause you already have a user model. Your code will work after some analyze and enhancements, but i will highly recomend you to make something like this inuser model instead:

`public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','followers','user_id','follower_id');
}`
`public function following_users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','followers','follower_id','user_id');
}`

Than you can access a followers `$user->followers` (this will return eloquent collection and you will be able to do whatever you want with this according to laravel docs [collection api](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections)) and a certain one like `$user->followers[0]`

Hope i get your answer rigth.